# Mariadb thread stuck with status 'reset for next command'

Tags: php, performance, mariadb

We have a performance issue here with some LAMP apps, i saw some transactions in mariadb getting stuck in 'Reset for next command' status for many seconds (sometimes > 20s !).

```
 id         User       Host                 db      Command    Time         State                     Info      Progress
 300        user1   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51238   db_01   Sleep      14                                     NULL      0.000
 569        user1   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51634   NULL    Connect    14           Reset for next command    NULL      0.000
```

What do this status means ?

Should we investigate on the mariadb side (something like parsing issues ?) or app server side ?

Thanks for your advice